# How to refactor a for loop that search for text in a list of strings

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, refactoring, java-stream

I would like to refactor the below code to utilize the Stream() method but can't figure out how to do it.

Given the variable sentences is a List of Strings and is prepopulated with:
"Jack went to the park",
"Mary stayed home",
"Chris went to work"

How would I use Stream() to return the entire line that contains the word "home"

```
List<String> sentences = new ArrayList<>();
sentences.add("Jack went to the park");
sentences.add("Mary stayed home");
sentences.add("Chris went to work");

for (int I=0; I < sentences.size(); I++) {
   if (sentences.get(I).contains("home")) {
      return sentences.get(I);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sentences.stream()
    .filter(str -> str.contains("home"))
    .findAny()
    .orElse("String to return if string which contains home was not found");`
```

Or you can check result of `Optional`, this code will be absolutely equivalent to yours:

```
Optional<String> result = sentences.stream()
    .filter(str -> str.contains("home"))
    .findAny()

if (result.isPresent()) {
    return result.get();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Chmilevfa for providing both answers. I was trying to use lambda but couldn't get it to work.